# SLRequest Handling Facebook Token Expiring, etc

Tags: ios, facebook

In my app, I have a view for Settings with a UISegmentControl set to Yes or No to allow automatic posting of a page viewed to Facebook using SLRequest and Accounts Framework.  The flow of it is like this:

It is automatically set to No.  When the user clicks Yes it runs this code:

```
-(void)facebookpost {
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    // We will pass this dictionary in the next method. It should contain your Facebook App ID key,
    // permissions and (optionally) the ACFacebookAudienceKey
    NSDictionary *options = @{ACFacebookAppIdKey : @"APPID",
    ACFacebookPermissionsKey : @[@"email", @"publish_stream"],
ACFacebookAudienceKey:ACFacebookAudienceFriends};

    // Request access to the Facebook account.
    // The user will see an alert view when you perform this method.
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType
                                          options:options
                                       completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                           if (granted)
                                           {
                                               // At this point we can assume that we have access to the Facebook account
                                               NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];

                                               // Optionally save the account
                                               [accountStore saveAccount:[accounts lastObject] withCompletionHandler:nil];
                                           }
                                           else
                                           {
                                               [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"facebook"];
                                               [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
                                               NSLog(@"Failed to grant access\n%@", error);
                                           }
                                       }];

}
```

It also sets the Bool Value to YES for a NSUserDefault Key for facebookposting.

Then, in code later on, when a page is viewed, this code is ran if the value of facebookposting is YES.  If NO, it simply never runs this code:

```
-(void)writetowall {
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

    // If we don't have access to users Facebook account, the account store will return an empty array.
    if (accounts.count == 0)
        return;

    // Since there's only one Facebook account, grab the last object
    ACAccount *account = [accounts lastObject];

    // Create the parameters dictionary and the URL (!use HTTPS!)
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"message" : @"MY MESSAGE", @"link": _entry.articleUrl};
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];

    // Create request
    SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                            requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                      URL:URL
                                               parameters:parameters];

    // Since we are performing a method that requires authorization we can simply
    // add the ACAccount to the SLRequest
    [request setAccount:account];

    // Perform request
    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *respData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResp, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:respData
                                                                           options:kNilOptions
                                                                             error:&error];

        // Check for errors in the responseDictionary
    }];
}
```

What I am wondering is HOW and WHERE to handle things like permissions being removed from Facebook or password being changed, etc.  Does that need to be handled in the first set of code where permission is garnered?  Because, basically that set of code is ran just once, and the rest of the time it just runs the code to post to the wall.

Comment: I think I should be able to add `[accountStore renewCredentialsForAccount:account completion:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult renewResult, NSError *error) {
        //we don't actually need to inspect renewResult or error.
        if (error){
            
        }
    }];` in the code to post to wall, but I'm unsure how to detect if the token has expired first.

Comment: Or, on the Class that handles posting (not initial authorization) can I simply add observer for account changed, and if that is triggered, run the renew?  When it renews, does it need the APPID again?